# Impute column value via mode based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a dataset that contains n columns. Those include a column for the Birth City and another for the Birth Country. What I want to do is, based on the Birth Country, I am going to get the mode of the Birth City, and use it for the missing values in the Birth City column.

I tried the following code, but nothing is affected.

```
df["Birth City"]= df.groupby('Birth Country')['Birth City'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))
df[df["Birth City"].isnull()]
```

After executing the above code, I still get the same missing Birth City values.

Comment: could you show an example of your dataframe?

Comment: @ansev i edited my question to include a screenshot of my dataframe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
A screen shot or off-site link is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `x.fillna(x.mode())` with `x.mode()[0]` in your code

```
df["Birth City"]= df.groupby('Birth Country')['Birth City'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
df[df["Birth City"].isnull()]
```

In your example you are trying to use `Series.transform` which applies `lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode())`. This lambda function replaces x with `x.fillna(x.mode())` (not `x.mode()`) which [equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to Series with missing values filled.
`x.mode()` also has type `Series` and equals to Series of modes in sorted order, so you have to use `x.mode()[0]`

Comment: I got index out of bounds first, but then when I analyzed the data I found that one of the missing records doesn't have a mode, as it is the only occurring Birth Country